# SonarRunner failed - Analysis is already running

Tags: exception, jenkins, sonarqube

Hi I'm running a Jenkins build with sonarRunner (in Gradle) and during this sonarRunner task, it's failing with the following error message. Any ideas! how to fix it?

```
09:57:21.410 ERROR - It looks like an analysis of 'MyProject' is already running (started less than a minute ago).
:****Runner FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':****Runner'.
> org.****.api.utils.SonarException: The project is already being analysed.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK, that was quick.

I used `-Dsonar.forceAnalysis=true` and the error went away.

Comment: I believe this is deprecated now.